# Parsing a Log File to Display Data from Multiple Lines Using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex, logging

So I'm trying to parse a bit of code here to get message text from a log file. I'll explain as I go. Here's the code:

```
// Print to interactions
  try
  {
  // assigns the input file to a filereader object
     BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(log));

      sc = new Scanner(log);
            while(sc.hasNext())
              {
                 String line=sc.nextLine();
                   if(line.contains("LANTALK")){
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line);
                    Element idto = doc.select("MBXTO").first();
                    Element  msg = doc.select("MSGTEXT").first();
                    System.out.println(" to " + idto.text() + " " + 
                        msg.text());
                    System.out.println();

                   } // End of if

               } // End of while


  try
  {
   // Print to output file
      sc = new Scanner (log);
            while(sc.hasNext())
              {
                 String line=sc.nextLine();
                   if(line.contains("LANTALK")){
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(line);
                    Element idto = doc.select("MBXTO").first();
                    Element  msg = doc.select("MSGTEXT").first();
                    outFile.println(" to " + idto.text() + " " + 
                        msg.text());
                    outFile.println();     
                    outFile.println();
               } // End of if

               } // End of while
    } // end of try
```

I'm getting input from a log file, here's a sample of what it looks like and the lines that I'm filtering out:

```
08:25:20.740 [D] [T:000FF0] [F:LANTALK2C] <CMD>LANMSG</CMD>
<MBXID>1124</MBXID><MBXTO>5760</MBXTO><SUBTEXT>LanTalk</SUBTEXT><MOBILEADDR>
</MOBILEADDR><LAP>0</LAP><SMS>0</SMS><MSGTEXT>and I talked to him and he 
gave me a credit card number</MSGTEXT>
08:25:20.751 [+] [T:000FF0] [S:1:1:1124:5607:5] LANMSG [15/2 | 0]
08:25:20.945 [+] [T:000FF4] [S:1:1:1124:5607:5] LANMSGTYPESTOPPED [0/2 | 0]
08:25:21.327 [+] [T:000FE8] [S:1:1:1124:5607:5] LANMSGTYPESTARTED [0/2 | 0]
```

So far, I've been able to filter the line that contains the message (`LANMSG`). And from that, I've been able to get the id number of the recipient (`MBXTO`). But the next line contains the sender's id, which I need to pull out and display. (`[S:1:1:1124:SENDERID:5]`). How should I do this? Below is a copy of the output I'm getting:

```
to 5760 and I talked to him and he gave me a credit card number
```

And here's what I need to get:

```
SENDERID to 5760 and I talked to him and he gave me a credit card number
```

Any help you guys could give me on this would be great. I'm just not sure how to go about getting the information I need.

Comment: You've posted way too much code here for this question.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on this.  A few basic points:

Why do you create a BufferedReader that you never use?  
You should really use try-with-resources rather than try-finally as you have.  
The formating of this makes it really hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer isn't clear enough, but as it seems like you have not used regex in this code... remember to specify what have you tried before asking.
Anyways the regex you're searching for is:

```
(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})\s\[D\].+<MBXID>(\d+)<\/MBXID><MBXTO>(\d+)<\/MBXTO>.+<MSGTEXT>(.+)<\/MSGTEXT>
```

[Working example in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CCJ840/2)
It should capture:
**$1**: `08:25:20.740` 
**$2**: `1124` 
**$3**: `5760` 
**$4**: `and I talked to him and he 
gave me a credit card number` (Note that it also capture \n, or newline, characters).

(Also, you'll use `matcher.group(number)` instead of `$number` in Java).

And then you can use these substitution (group reference) terms to get your formatted output.

E.g.:  `$1 [$2] to [$3] $4`

Should return:

```
08:25:20.740 [1124] to [5760] and I talked to him and he
gave me a credit card number
```

Remember, when you're going to implement regex in your Java code, you must escape all the backslashes (`\`), for this reason, this regex looks bigger:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}\\.\\d{3})\\s\\[D\\].+<MBXID>(\\d+)<\\/MBXID><MBXTO>(\\d+)<\\/MBXTO>.+<MSGTEXT>(.+)<\\/MSGTEXT>", Pattern.MULTILINE + Pattern.DOTALL); 
// Multiline is used to capture the LANMSG more than once, and Dotall is used to make the '.' term in regex also match the newline in the input
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()){
    String output = matcher.group(1) + " [" + matcher.group(2) + "] to [" + matcher.group(3) + "] " + matcher.group(4);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

And for your second problem <strike>Oh, you have edited and erased it already. . . But I'll still answer</strike>:
You can parse the `$2` and `$3` and make them return an integer:

```
int id1 = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
int id2 = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
```

This way you can create a method to return a name for these IDs. e.g.:
 `UserUtil.getName(int id)`

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on the last part for parsing 2 and 3 and the method creation? I'm afraid I'm a little lost.

Comment: @AlexanderVassios this is not that easy, I mean, every single ID must have an equivalent username, where are you storing all the IDs and names?

Comment: That's fine. I can take the time to assign Names to the ID's. I literally have a piece of paper with the names corresponding to the ID's.

Comment: I just need to create a method that lays that all out, and then call on that method when I need it. Right?

Comment: Yep. Here is an example of a method that can return names for certain IDs, but if you're going to use a lot of names, switch may not be the best way, use a `for each` loop instead. https://pastebin.com/PfBm6pih

Comment: That helps. Thanks!

Comment: Okay so how would I connect the method with the text being read in? I placed the method before main. Do I have to call the method before I use `Pattern.compile` and return them as an integer as you described above?

Comment: Nope, just use it in the System##println method:
`String output = matcher.group(1) + " [" + getUsername(id1) + "] to [" + getUsername(id2) + "] " + matcher.group(4);` (Note: `id1` and `id2` were defined inside the `while(matcher.find())` loop.)